# expo init/npm init criando muitos arquivos

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, módulo-ecmascript

Boa tarde, gente.
Estou com um certo problema ao executar o `expo init app`. O comando **funciona**, cria os arquivos react-native no meu Windows corretamente, mas de um tempo para cá, ele deixou de criar apenas 3 pastas e 5 arquivos (mais ou menos isso). E o template que estou usando ainda é o mesmo *blank*.

Agora o comando `expo init app` cria, ainda as 3 pastas, mas mais uma dezena de outros arquivos **.cmd** e **.ps1**, fiz uma lista com o nome deles:

atob,
browserlist,
color-support,
envinfo,
esparse,
esvalidate,
image-size,
is-ci,
jetifier,
jetifier-standalone,
jetify,
js-yaml,
jsesc,
json5,
logkitty,
loose-envify,
md5-file,
metro,
metro-inspector,
metro-symbolicate,
mime,
mkdirp,
parser,
react-native,
regjsparser,
rimraf,
sane,
semver,
uglifyjs,
uuid,
watch,
which

Não sei porque isso acontece, gostaria de saber se tem como impedir a criação desses arquivos? E se tem como impedir, como proceder, por favor?

Comment: Isso não são arquivos dentro do `node_modules`?

Comment: Sim, a maioria desses arquivos tem um pasta equivalente dentro de node_modules. Mas a questão é que antes ele não criava esses arquivos, também não me lembro de os instalar.

Answer (score 1):

Isto ocorre devido a atualização (que ocorre em segundo plano) do SDK do Expo (talvez esteja na versão 37). Esse update veio cheio de features, e bugs também. Eles adicionaram diversos arquivos por padrão, logo, você não poderá fazer um controle disso.